# When does the Bible come up in "Miss Bernard said"?

Tags: miss-bernard-said

Prior to watching the anime adaptation, I read descriptions of *Miss Bernard said* (*Bernard-jou Iwaku*) in [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/33462/Bernard-jou_Iwaku) and [the Fall 2016 chart linked to in the Anime.SE chat](https://static.neregate.com/2016/09/neregate.com-Fall-2016-Anime-Chart-v3.png). Both mention that the Bible comes up in at least one conversation in the series. Despite this, I do not recall ever seeing a discussion of or an allusion to Bible in the anime shorts, which I found a bit disappointing — I would have liked to see how they approached the subject.

In this case, seeing that Bible was mentioned in the show description in the first place, it seems likely that it at least appears once in the manga. Am I correct, and if so, where does it appear? (Alternatively, did I overlook some details in the anime?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bible does come up at least once in the manga. There is a two-page segment in volume 1, chapter 4 (p. 35-36), titled "The Bible said" (「聖書曰く」). It's kinda loony, like everything else in *Miss Bernard said*.

[image: volume 1, chapter 4, page 35]
[image: volume 1, chapter 4, page 36]

#### Page 35

> **Panel 1**
>   NARRATION: Miss Bernard, a.k.a. Machida Sawako, was reading in the library, as was her habit. *World-Famous Adages You'll Love to Use* was one of her favorites.
>
> **Panel 2**
>   SAWAKO: Hmm.
>   NARRATION: What was Miss 'ard planning to do with these adages?
>
> **Panel 3**
>   SAWAKO: When aliens attack and bring about the end of the world, I want to murmur a verse from the Bible as I stand there petrified... but I can't find anything suitable in here.
>
> **Panel 4**
>   SAWAKO: Like, "the scales fell from my eyes" is apparently from the New Testament, but that's so lame.
>
> **Panel 5**
>   VOICE: Aliens have attacked! The end of the world is nigh!
>
> **Panel 6**
>   SAWAKO: The scales have fallen from my eyes... I guess?

#### Page 36

> **Panel 1**
>   SAWAKO: Argh! This is no good! I need something more... Apocalyptic...
>
> **Panel 2**
>   BIBLE: And the great city was divided into three parts, and the cities of the nations fell: and great Babylon came in remembrance before God, to give unto her the cup of the wine of the fierceness of his wrath. [...] and men blasphemed God because of the plague of the hail; for the plague thereof was exceeding great.
>
> **Panel 3**
>   ENDOU: Revelation, chapter 16...
>
> **Panel 4**
>   SAWAKO: That's too long! I'm not feeling it!!
>
> **Panel 5**
>   SAWAKO: Oh. I found something good.
>
> **Panel 6**
>   SAWAKO: When the aliens eat us, I'll say this verse!
>   ENDOU: Them eating us is a done deal?
>
> **Panel 7**
>   SAWAKO: [Except a corn of wheat fall into the ground and die, it abideth alone: but if it die, it bringeth forth much fruit.](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2012%3A24%2CRevelation%2017&version=KJV)

There may be other references to the Bible (I haven't read much past this chapter). If I do run into any more, I'll try to remember to update this answer.